# accessing 2 viewControllers

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating an ipad application, I two view controllers the size screen of an iphone 5 and I would like to show both of them on the ipad screen, as two distinct UIViewControllers though. Is there a way to do it?
I have tried to alloc the second viewcnotrller in the viewdidload of the first, but what I notice is that it alloc the first and the second, but the first is not accessible any more (it looks just like a still image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it very easily in the storyboard. Just add 2 container views (next to the regular UIViews in the object list) to your controller's view, and size them how you want. You will automatically get 2 view controllers connected to the container views by an embed segue. Just change the class of these 2 controllers to your custom classes, and you should be good to go. If you need to get a reference to these controllers from the main controller, you can get it from the childViewControllers property. Your main controller (assuming it's the initial controller) and the 2 child controllers will all be instantiated at start up with no code necessary.

Comment: The only thing is that the views load and display the content (buttons, UITableview)...but the UITableView doesn't actually load the data, and when I press the buttons nothing happens. when I instead remove the container views and test the two ViewControllers separately, they work perfectly. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Alessandro It's hard to tell without knowing what you did. I've done this multiple times, and it should work. Did you add any code in the app delegate or in the main view controller (the one that has the container views)? You should update your question to show what you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [view controller containment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81), in which you have a container view controller, which then can load one or more children view controllers. Also see the relevant section in the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6). Also see the WWDC 2011 session, [Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102).